# Running phpunit to test composer plugin vfsStream

Tags: phpunit, composer-php, phpstorm

Using PHPStorm on a project with Composer and PHPUnit (all of which have already work correctly) how do I run PHPUnit test on a composer plugin inside "vendor" in this case mikey179/vfsStream?

My project structure looks like this:

```
myscripts/
vendor/
- mikey179
  - vfsStream
composer.json
```

I want to run PHPUnit to test vfsStream plugin.

I was able to run Testing on my own test code (outside vendor directory).

When I run PHPUnit test (That little green play button on top) I got the following:

```
usr/bin/php /tmp/ide-phpunit.php --bootstrap /path/to/project/vendor/autoload.php --configuration /path/to/project/vendor/mikey179/vfsStream/phpunit.xml.dist /path/to/project/vendor/mikey179/vfsStream
Testing started at 5:53 PM ...
PHPUnit 3.8-g8d770d8 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /path/to/project/vendor/mikey179/vfsStream/phpunit.xml.dist



Time: 2.22 seconds, Memory: 2.25Mb

No tests executed!

PHP Warning:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /path/to/project/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML.php on line 127
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:0
PHP   2. IDE_Base_PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:506
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:268
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /path/to/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:173
PHP   5. PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML->process() /path/to/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:465
PHP   6. date() /path/to/project/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/HTML.php:127
Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Oops, forgotten to put that in. I have edited my question.

Comment: Well .. based on what I see from your output (test runner) you have set it up correctly (the PHPUnit Run/Debug Configuration). Ignoring the PHP's warning about the missing timezone (edit your php.ini to fix that) ... the only issue that I see is the fact that test runner is unable to find any tests to run. For that -- please show the screenshots with file names (or give a link to that `vfsStream` if it's publicly available). Most likely tests are not following standard naming rules .. or no tests were actually selected.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see **it's an issue with PhpStorm's helper/wrapper script** (`/tmp/ide-phpunit.php`), which is used for integration purposes (track tests progress in real time -- messages must be formatted in specific way; etc).

Test files do not have standard and expected `Test.php` ending -- instead they have custom `TestCase.php` .. and helper script seems to be unable to apply that config option from `phpunit.xml.dist` file correctly (it will search for `*Test.php` files only).

**If you rename** all `*TestCase.php` file to be `*Test.php` it will start working in PhpStorm (I've renamed just a few .. and they got detected and executed just fine).

---

Right now I may only suggest to either rename test files as described above (which is not a good idea in long run if you plan to run those tests on regular basis and keep downloading latest sources of that library) or **submit a bug ticket to PhpStorm Issue Tracker** explaining the situation: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI and hopefully devs will fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You don't run a test on a package in vendor/. You clone the repo and follow the instructions they've given in the testing documentation. In the case of mikey179/vfsStream, there's a github repo: https://github.com/bovigo/vfsStream and it even has a .travis.yml file you can read for inspiration: https://github.com/bovigo/vfsStream/blob/master/.travis.yml

If you're concerned that you've got a version of vfsstream that doesn't pass tests, then you can look at the version that's installed in your project with `composer show mikey179/vfsStream` and then check out that tag in the repo before running the tests.

The reason is that the package might very well have different dev dependencies than your project, so no matter what else you do you'll end up with broken test runs. Composer ignores dev dependencies for packages other than the main project.